# Refresh Page but keep scoll position with countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, page-refresh

So I have this bit of code which refresh the page after the countdown timer has reached 0. The countdown is displayed in a div at the bottom.

```
<script>
    (function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining === 0)
        location.reload(true);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
})(60);
</script>

<span id="countdown" class="bold"></span>
```

I would like it to refresh the same way but keep the scroll position on the browser as the page is pretty long. Would this be possible with this code?

Please give example as I don't understand javascript all that much..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used localStorage or cookies before? These are handy parts of your user's browsers where you can actually store and save custom bits of data, just for them. See [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for some more info.

Anyways, you could use localStorage, and then when your user scrolls you could just store how far down they were. Then, on page load, if that localStorage key has a value, scroll the user down that far.

I made a snippet but, sadly, their iframe for snippets won't allow me to access localStorage to actually show you how it works in action. But, I did put some lines in there anyways (untested, though) with some comments to try and help illustrate the broad strokes of how you could go about it.

The only other thing you could do on top of this is put in a test to make sure their browser supports localStorage and then, if it doesn't, you could fall back to trying to use cookies or some other method!

```js
function updateScrollStuff() {
  // this tells us how far down we've scrolled as a number, like '476'
  var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
  
  // I cant access localStorage from the iframe they're using here, but I think this
  // would be what you'd want to do with it to store that scroll position
  // localStorage.storedScrollPosition = scrollPosition;

  // this line is just illustrative, showing you that the number for the scroll position is updating
  // every time you scroll - you don't need this for your final purposes
  $("#scroll-position").text(scrollPosition + "px");
}

// when the user scrolls, call that function above
$(window).scroll(function() {
  updateScrollStuff();
});

// I can't test it here, but on page load I would check to
// see if a value exists, and then scroll to it if it does!
$(window).load(function() {
  // again, with local storage blocked all I can do is show you what
  // it would look like
  // typeof 'undefined' is just a check you can make to see if a variable exists
  // if (typeof localStorage.storedScrollPosition != 'undefined') {
  //   $("html, body").scrollTop(localStorage.storedScrollPosition);
  // }
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#section-1 {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#section-2 {
  background-color: #666666;
}

#section-3 {
  background-color: #999999;
}

#section-4 {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

#scroll-position {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-1" class="section"></div>
<div id="section-2" class="section"></div>
<div id="section-3" class="section"></div>
<div id="section-4" class="section"></div>
<h3 id="scroll-position">Scroll to see this change</h3>
```